# Javascript and Flash: is it possible to detach a javascript command triggered from flash?

Tags: javascript, flash

I have a flash animation running in the browser that has a 'close' link and by clicking it, a `history.back()` JavaScript command is triggered.

How can I prevent this command from runinng without editing the .fla script itself? Why? Because there are tons of these files and editing one by one is simply not possible.

Is there a way to do this at run time?

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: `history.back()` is not an event. Also, this question looks like work that you're supposed to do on your own. At the very least, rewrite the question so it sounds like your own.

Comment: @JuanMendes I don't know how one could make that assumption based on a question regarding a javascript command triggered from a flash script, but well. And with that line, almost all question in SO can be considered things that people should handle themselves, right?

Comment: try history.go = function(){}; hope this work

Comment: @darksoulsong Sorry, I probably didn't express myself properly. My assumption is from the fact that your question says "Imagine you have a flash animation", "You need to figure a way". I've edited your question to be what I would have expected it to look like.

Comment: @JuanMendes Not a problem. Thanks for the edit. It sounds better now.

Answer (score 1):

try this in your javascript

```
history.go = function(){};
```

this will override default method

hope this will help you

Comment: Do you mean `history.back = function(){}`? This does have the side effect of also preventing anything that calls `history.go|back` outside of Flash

Comment: By the way, I do think this is the only way to prevent it without modifying the source